Can a minimal separating set in a chordal graph ever be maximal?
I'm currently reading Daphne Koller's book on Probabilistic Graphical Models, and, in the proof of theorem 4.12, the authors state something that I cannot wrap my head around.
The authors state that in an undirected chordal graph, a minimal separating set $\mathbf{S}$ for two variables, $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ can either be a subset of a maximal clique or a maximal clique on its own. While I understand why $\mathbf{S}$ is complete subgraph and how $\mathbf{S}$ can be a subset of a maximal clique, I do not understand how it can be a maximal clique on its own. It seems to me that the requirement that the graph be chordal necessarily makes $\mathbf{S}$ a subset of maximal clique.
To recap the statement of the theorem and the outline of the proof: Theorem 4.12 Every undirected chordal graph $\mathcal{H}$ has a clique tree $\mathcal{T}$. The proof goes like this:

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be an undirected, chordal graph of size > 1.
Two nodes $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ are connected, but not directly.
Let $\mathbf{S}$ be a minimal subset of nodes that separates $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$.
Let $\mathbf{W_{1}}$ and $\mathbf{W_{2}}$ be some partition of the variables $\mathcal{X}-\mathcal{S}$ into two disjoint components, such that $\mathbf{W_{i}}$ encompasses the connected component containing $X_{i}$.
Create an induced graph $\mathcal{H_{1}} = \mathcal{H}[\mathbf{W_{1} \cup \mathbf{S}}]$.

It is after this step that the authors state:

"Beacuse $\mathbf{S}$ is a complete connected subgraph, it is either a maximal clique or a subset of some maximal clique in $\mathcal{H}$"

How can $\mathbf{S}$ be a maximal clique on its own?

Stipulating that S can't be a maximal clique, the statement is still true. The author may just not have wanted to prove that S can't be maximal clique because "maximal clique or subset" is good enough.

Interesting observation, thank you @ThomasLumley. The authors do spend some time on the case where $\mathbf{S}$ is a maximal clique later in the proof, but it is one or two sentences. I've found one other reference in another class mentioning that $\mathbf{S}$ can be maximal.
